# How to group in ranges a sorted array of integers in Bash

Tags: bash

In bash I'have a sorted integer array like:

```
array[0]=1
array[1]=2
array[2]=3
array[3]=4
array[4]=7
array[5]=9
array[6]=10
array[7]=13
array[8]=15
array[9]=16
```

And I want to obtain output like:

> 1-4,7,9-10,13,15-16

There is a simple and fast way to do it?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, already corrected the question. It's a sorted array of integers.

Comment: Is there any logic for this grouping or it is just random?

Comment: To me it looks like its grouped by contiguous numbers? Like 11,12,13,15 become 11-13,15

Comment: Just as Jite said, the grouping is done by contiguous/sequential numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any standard ways of doing it, but it shouldn't be that hard to write your own function to do it. Something in the lines of:

- Save the first array elements 'value' as 'low'
- Iterate over the array and save current 'index' as 'high'
- When array 'value' differs from 'index', print out 'low-high' IF not 'low == high', then print 'low'
- Reset 'low' and 'index' to current 'value' and continue
- Increase 'index' by one

Should be simple enough pseudo for a pre-sorted non-empty integer array :)

(Sorry about formatting, I'm currently on a Mac with a PC keyboard and I don't get along with it very well.)

Comment: Thxs for the answer Jite, my initial approach was to iterate over the array elements, looking if the current element is equal to the previous element-1, if not ending the current range with the past element and starting a new range. But I thought there should be a more elegant way to do it.

Comment: Yeah it was the same approach I was trying to explain. Like checking if `(curr-1) == prev` and that you need to save the index/value of the starting element in a range since it a range may reach over several elements. Regarding solutions: someone has to iterate over the array, whether its your code, an external script or another binary is up to you :)

Comment: Thxs very much, I accepted your answer. Will continue with this approach. Also as a note, if starting element equals last element in rage, only print the element instead of starting_element-last_element.

Comment: @Gakushū-sha: Yeah, thats what I meant with `IF not 'low == high', then print 'low'`, as in: it was only one number in this range :) Good luck with your solution.